# Converting html (with css) table to PDF using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, html-table

I have a report in a form of HTML table. This table is a bit large or wide that the browser creates a scroll in the x-axis. I have to scroll in x-axis or zoom-out to see the whole table. I would like to use Javascript to convert this HTML table (with the CSS) to PDF format for printing out purposes. I thought that having a wide table makes taking screenshots is not an option.

So any ideas how do I do this considering the 2 points:

1. The report table is wide.
2. I want the CSS to go with the HTML to the pdf format.

Comment: you want css and html in the pdf?

Comment: jsPDF is good for this sort of thing, but this question is way too broad, SO is for question-answer, not brainstorming general solutions.

Answer (score -2):

What about using [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)?

Have you tried using it or even googling for this before posting here?

Comment: This Q should be closed, not answered. SO is not a place to request links to libraries. A simple google for `convert HTML to PDF` would get one to  the same link.

Comment: I was just suggesting, sorry for trying to help people. Its not necessary to be so mean... Edited my answer to fit the LTMGTFY term..

Comment: I'm also suggesting and trying to help.

Comment: Guys, I have been googling this for 2 days before posting the question. I hv found these jsPDF and html2canvas stuff. I tried jsPDF andI had it working but not as I wanted to be. 1) It does not take the css with the html (this is what I asked about). 2) It gives me a pdf file with everything in one column. 3) To take the css I thought I could take a screen shot but the table is wide with a scroll so I couldn't (this is also my question).